# Database notifications don't show up after testing notify

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, notifications, eloquent, phpunit

I have a unit test with the following:

```
use \Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification;

public function testMailSentAndLogged()
{
    Notification::fake();

    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $emailAddress = $user->emailAddress;
    $emailAddress->notify(new UserCreated);

    Notification::assertSentTo(
        $emailAddress,
        UserCreated::class
    );

    error_log('DatabaseNotification '.print_r(DatabaseNotification::get()->toArray(), 1));
    $this->assertEquals(1, $emailAddress->notifications->count());

}
```

My Notification has this for the `via()`:

```
public final function via($notifiable)
{
    // complex logic...

    error_log('mail, database');
    return ['mail', 'database'];
}
```

The code fails on the `$this->assertEquals` code. the error_log produces the following:

```
[03-Jan-2018 01:23:01 UTC] mail, database
[03-Jan-2018 01:23:01 UTC] DatabaseNotification Array
(
)
```

WHY don't the `$emailAddress->notifications` pull up anything? Why doesn't `DatabaseNotification::get()` pull anything?;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test, you are calling the method

```
Notification::fake();
```

As stated in [Laravel's documentation on Mocking](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mocking#notification-fake),

> You may use the Notification facade's fake method to prevent
>   notifications from being sent.

Actually, this bit of code is the assertion that the Notification would have been sent, under normal circumstances (ie in prod) :

```
Notification::assertSentTo();
```

If you remove the call to Notification::fake(), your notification should appear in your testing database.

So you kinda have two solutions. The first one is to remove the call to fake(), thus really sending the notification, which will appear in the database. the second is not to test if the notification was written successfully in the database : it's Laravel's responsibility, not your application's. I recommand the second solution :)

Comment: Just experienced this. After commenting out `Notification::fake()` , it worked.